# How to check "_custom_access" for whole website and not module/path?

Tags: drupal-8

```
example:
  path: '/example'
  defaults:
    _controller: '\Drupal\example\Controller\ExampleController::content'
  requirements:
    _custom_access: '\Drupal\example\Controller\ExampleController::access'
```

This custom_access checker will be executed only when someone call **mywebsite.domain/example**.

But I want that this controller check all urls, run independent of path.

How can I create an independent custom access controller?

Answer (score 0):

The idea for preventing routing access to a very low level (`Kernel` one to be precise), is to register a `EventSubscriber` service, subscribing to the `REQUEST` KernelEvent.

1. First of all, you will need to create a [new custom module](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/creating-custom-modules).
2. Once done, you will be able to create a new `my_module.services.yml` file which will declare a new `EventSubscriber`

```
services:
  my_module.subscriber:
    class: Drupal\my_module\EventSubscriber\MyCustomSubscriber
    tags:
      - { name: event_subscriber}
```

3. Then, create the class referenced above in `my_module/src/EventSubscriber/MyCustomSubscriber.php`.
   Here is a tiny example which checks if the current user is logged-in before accessing any page, otherwise redirect on the login page. This following code is not complete (see the last reference for a better explanation) but it shows you the basics (subscription to the event, dependency injection, event redirection, ...)

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\my_module\EventSubscriber;

use Drupal\Core\Routing\RouteMatchInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Url;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseEvent;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\KernelEvents;

class MyCustomSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface {

  /**
   * The current route match.
   *
   * @var \Drupal\Core\Routing\RouteMatchInterface
   */
  protected $routeMatch;

  /**
   * Class constructor.
   *
   * @param \Drupal\Core\Routing\RouteMatchInterface $route_match
   *   The current route match.
   */
  public function __construct(RouteMatchInterface $route_match) {
    $this->routeMatch = $route_match;
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  static function getSubscribedEvents() {
    $events[KernelEvents::REQUEST][] = ['isLoggedIn'];
    return $events;
  }

  /**
   * It verify the page is requested by a logged in user, otherwise prevent access.
   *
   * @param \Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseEvent $event
   *   A response for a request.
   */
  public function isLoggedIn(GetResponseEvent $event) {
    $route_name = $this->routeMatch->getRouteName();

    // Don't run any assertion on the login page, to prevent any loop redirect.
    // If intend to be used on a production project, please @see
    // https://www.lucius.digital/en/blog/drupal-8-development-always-redirect-all-logged-out-visitors-to-the-login-page for a better implementation.
    if ($route_name === 'user.login') {
      return;
    }

    if (\Drupal::currentUser()->isAnonymous()) {
      $dest = Url::fromRoute('user.login')->toString();
      $event->setResponse(RedirectResponse::create($dest));
    }
  }
}
```

To go further, you may read those explanations of registering event subscribers & some use case:

- [Responding to Events in Drupal 8](https://drupalize.me/blog/201502/responding-events-drupal-8)
- [How to Register an Event Subscriber in Drupal 8](https://www.chapterthree.com/blog/how-to-register-event-subscriber-drupal8)
- [Always redirect all logged out visitors to the login page](https://www.lucius.digital/en/blog/drupal-8-development-always-redirect-all-logged-out-visitors-to-the-login-page)

I hope it will help you.